# Equivalent of ItemUtils.toAttributeValue in DynamoDB JDK 2.X?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In [com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle 1.X](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:aws-java-sdk-bundle), there is a convenient helper method [`ItemUtils.toAttributeValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/ItemUtils.html#toAttributeValue-java.lang.Object-) that converts any `Object` to an `AttributeValue` with the right type:

```
        ... if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            return result.withBOOL((Boolean)value);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            return result.withS((String) value);
        } else if ( ...
```

Is there an equivalent of this method in AWS JDK 2.X? Specifically, I'm working with DynamoDB and [software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb 2.X](https://search.maven.org/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb). The `AttributeValue` classes in [1.X](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/AttributeValue.html) and [2.X](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html) aren't even the same, so using `ItemUtils.toAttributeValue` from 1.X is not an option.

Comment: Same issue, do you solve this problem? could you share your solution?

Comment: @王信凱 I did not find an official/useful solution. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59259103/3552532) below for what I did.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and reached this github issue. Hope this [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2628#issuecomment-1274373271) helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the mean time, I just replicated the functionalities I need from 1.X:

```
  static AttributeValue toAttributeValue(Object value) {
    if (value == null)                   return AttributeValue.builder().nul(true).build();
    if (value instanceof AttributeValue) return (AttributeValue) value;
    if (value instanceof String)         return AttributeValue.builder().s((String) value).build();
    if (value instanceof Number)         return AttributeValue.builder().n(value.toString()).build();

    if (value instanceof Map)            return AttributeValue.builder().m(
      ((Map<String, Object>) value).entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> toAttributeValue(e.getValue())
      ))).build();

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Time to impl new path for " + value);
  }
```

Comment: Better try this [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2628#issuecomment-1274373271).